# How to execute runMain from custom task?

Tags: sbt

I'm using sbt v0.13.5

In my project, I'd like to have an sbt task that can accept some input (a single string), do some work on it and spit back some output (again, a single string). I've created a helper class in my project that does this that I can call from the terminal via `sbt runMain` (`sbt "runMain com.example.utils.ClassName someArgument"`).

What I'd like is to save myself some typing and have an sbt task that does this. I'd like to just be able to type `sbt doThing withStuff` and have a taskKey named `doThing` that calls `runMain` with the name of the class to run and whatever argument was passed in.

I know how to create tasks but I can't seem to figure out how to call `runMain` from a custom task definition in my build.sbt. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```scala
TaskKey[Unit]("myTask") := (runMain in Compile).toTask(" com.example.Main arg1 arg2").value
```

`runMain` is an `InputTask`. `InputTask` has `toTask` method since 0.13.1.

- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/9dcb8727d819fb
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.6/main/settings/src/main/scala/sbt/InputTask.scala#L33
- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html#Get+a+Task+from+an+InputTask

Comment: What a **clever** one-liner to define a task key and call `:=`.

Comment: Nice one! Folks, don't underestimate the white space in the `toTask(" com.example.Main arg1 arg2")` , it is not typo nor formatting error, its needed.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody wanted to run the main class with arguments computed basing on settings, you need [dynamic tasks](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Dynamic-Task.html). For example:

```scala
val myRun = taskKey[Unit]("...")

myRun := Def.taskDyn {
  val appName = name.value
  Def.task {
    (runMain in createApi in Compile)
      .toTask(s" com.softwaremill.MyMain $appName")
      .value
  }
}.value
```